# How to change and reload python code in waitress without restarting the server?

Tags: python, development-environment, waitress

I am using waitress to serve the web application content like.

`waitress-serve --port=8000 myapp:application`

While developing, as I change code, I continuously had to restart the waitress-serve to see my changes. Is there a standard way I can automate this?

Comment: If you are changing python code, then you'll have to restart the server. HTML code will change in the next request

Comment: Is your application written with 
[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/34/)? Then you might want to try [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/34/), it works for me together with `waitress`.
Apart from that, have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ReloadWSGI and https://github.com/loomchild/reload . I have not tried any of them yet but the description seems to fit the use case.

Comment: @Dirk That snippet you mention....link is broken.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question but I had a similar issue trying to enable hot reload functionality for my REST API using Falcon framework.

Waitress does not monitor file changes but you could use `hupper` on top of it. Pretty simple:

```
$ pip install hupper
$ hupper -m waitress --port=8000 myapp:application
```

It works on Windows too.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comment by @Dirk, I found [the archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20101231083503/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/34/) to the snippet mentioned. I was able to get Waitress reloading by using Werkseug directly. Using Werkzeug's decorator `run_with_reloader` causes the app to restart whenever a Python file changes. (Werkzeug is used within Flask so it should be available).

Additionally, the `app.debug = True` line causes Flask to reload template files when they change. So you may want both considering your particular situation.

```py
import werkzeug.serving

@werkzeug.serving.run_with_reloader
def run_server():
    app.debug = True
    waitress.serve(app, listen='127.0.0.1:4432')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_server()
```

Once I had my server set up this way, it auto-reloaded the server whenever any file changed.

Comment: This work only with werkzeug version less than 2.1